# android market exclusion

Tags: android, google-play

My app is being filtered by the android market.  I have users contacting me because they cannot find my app in the market.  I allow them to download it from my website and it works perfectly.

Here is my manifest data:
Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here are the Android Market Messages:

This apk requests 4 permissions that users will be warned about
    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.CAMERA
    android.permission.VIBRATE
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

This apk requests 5 features that will be used for Android Market filtering
    android.hardware.camera
    android.hardware.camera.autofocus
    android.hardware.screen.landscape
    android.hardware.screen.portrait
    android.hardware.touchscreen

Looking in the market, there are hundreds of devices that are being excluded.  What can I do to remove these exclusions to be able to provide my app to these users?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove the permissions if you are using them in your application. Removing them and using the functions anyway would result in exceptions.

Other things that might cause the filtering could be the Content Rating, pricing or the country settings.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the min and max sdk level in your manifest might help as well.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#uses

Comment: might even want to add the new tags for screen size support while at it...  Unsure if that effects market visibility though.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

*If you request a hardware-related permission — CAMERA, for example — Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not offer it.
To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in  elements, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.*

So you probably need one of these too:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>`